# In Angular 4, how do I send data from one child component to another child of the same parent?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component P with two child components C1 and C2. C1 calls an API that responds with data that C2 will then use.

How do I pass data between C1 and C2 directly? If that's impossible, how do I send data from C1 to P and then to C2?

Comment: You can create a service and inject it into both components (best solution).  You could also set up an emitter pattern between the parent and children (other solution).  For the latter lookup Angular Input/Output.

Comment: If I inject a service, how does C2 know when to update after the service gets the response to C1?

Comment: You're looking for rxjs patterns, rxjs is a library that is included with Angular by default.  I would personally create an rxjs/behaviorsubject on the service and have C2 subscribe to it.  Read more about them here:  https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can share data through an observer.
Create a service and observe it wherever you need to access it.

I have answered a question please find the link here
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484433/nativescript-angular-2-hide-some-lines-of-app-component-html-in-specific-com/54485868#54485868)