# Reusing observables services in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service which is used to communicate between components and modules.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommunicationService<T> {

  private emitChanges = new Subject<T>();
  changes$ = this.emitChanges.asObservable();

  sendData(message: any) {
    this.emitChanges.next(message);
  }

  clearData() {
    this.emitChanges.next();
  }

  complete() {
    this.emitChanges.complete();
  }
}
```

Lets say I am sending a string from `Component 1`

```
export class Component1 {

  constructor(private comms: CommunicationService<string>){}

  onClick(){
    this.comms.sendData('hello');
  }
}
```

This is received in `Component 2`

```
export class Component2 implements OnDestroy {

  constructor(private comms: CommunicationService<string>){
    this.comms.changes$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }

  onDestroy(){
    this.comms.next();
    this.comms.close();
  }

}
```

Above code works fine, but when I try to reuse, the code in `component 3`, component 2 also receives the same data. In a border picture if I use a different data type, say an interface of different properties to another different property I get errors saying that a property doesn't exist.

Is there a way to reuse this service based on the `T`, and somewhere to check something like:

```
if (this.comms.changes$ instanceof Subscriber<someObject>){ // I know this is not possible
...
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is my answer related to your query
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484433/nativescript-angular-2-hide-some-lines-of-app-component-html-in-specific-com/54485868#54485868

Comment: That still triggers in another module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I have a suggestion. Currently you have 'providedIn: root' in your service. That means that there will be created only one instance of your service for the entire app, and any data you send to your Subject will be received by all components that subscribe to it.

It is possible to provide a service at the component level instead of the root level. To do this:

1. Remove the providedIn: root from your service, all you should be left with is @Injectable({})
2. For every component where you want an instance of your service you add the following inside the @Component: '@Component({providers: [ CommunicationService ]})'

Now you will have one instance of your service per component you provide it in.

Comment: Ya, I have the same issue even after doing this. It's being triggered in another component.

Comment: This should work and it is a regular feature of the Angular Dependency Injection system.

Comment: It is the case though that the service when provided in a component will be shared down to its children, but it will be different instances if the components are siblings

Comment: I am not sure why it is happening; this should work. Let me dig in.

Comment: Fixed it. I wasn't checking if a variable was null or not after unsubscribing it. Thank you for your help.